# What made Miss Vanessa Ives so desirable?

Tags: penny-dreadful

Over the course of three seasons of *Penny Dreadful*, we see miss Vanessa Ives being persued by both Lucifer and Dracula, who are brothers in the *Penny Dreadful* mythology.

**Why?**

What made her so special that two fallen angels were seeking her and fighting over her?

Comment: Maybe it's because she looks a lot like Eva Green.

Comment: @Ginasius - [She's oh, so pretty](http://cdn3.denofgeek.us/sites/denofgeekus/files/penny_dreadful_vanessa_ives.jpg)

Comment: @Ginasius - hell to the yes.  As to what made her so special, she was the one prophesied to bring the End of Days, so I'd think that would appeal to evil forces trying to destroy the Earth or, at least, plunge it into unfathomable and endless misery, even if she were not played by a smokin' hot actress.

Comment: On a side note, I'd definitely sell my soul to be Hecate's minion/love toy.

Answer (score 3):

In the first season of Penny Dreadful, there was an episode called "[Séance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQWtK6cdnYE)." Which was extremely creepy if you ask me because the name of the episode referred to the calling session they performed during a party.

[image: gif of the Séance]

During the episode "Séance" in season one, when *Evelyn Poole* donned her guise of *Madame Kali* and called the spirits, she referred to Vanessa as *Amunet*.

In *Ancient Egypt*, the West is the where the dead enter the underworld and *Amunet* is believed to be as the goddess who welcomes their entrance into the *Kingdom of Osiris*. She is believed to be the female form of the greater god Amun Ra and is one of the eight featured deities in the Ogdoad.

For many believers, *Amun-Ra* created himself. He was the ultimate creator.

Over the years, she became increasingly associated with *Iusaaset*, a shadow of *Atum*. This association made her the mother of all creation who owns the tree from which life emerged.

It was implied that even Ferdinand believes that Vanessa is the reincarnation of the goddess because after he told Sir Malcolm Murray about the prophecy, he warned him to keep it from his ward.

Vanessa was a natural-born witch, not a healer like Joan Clayton (Cut-Wife). Joan also revealed Vanessa is a very powerful witch.

Considering Vanessa's sigil is a scorpio, in ancient Egyptian mythology, there is a goddess named *Serket* who is often portrayed with a scorpion on the top of her head. She is an advisor to *Isis*, *the Queen of Heaven* and helps the other gods fight evil as well.

Meanwhile, *Amunet* is the consort of the god *Amun*-Ra, and is one of eight deities who helped to create the world.

If *Amunet* is an evil character in PD mythology, it is possible that executive producer John Logan might have taken liberties with merging two goddesses into same person. Vanessa's sigil could be a nod to her past life as *Amunet*.

Same assumption works for why Verbis Diablo went after Vanessa to hunt her. *Amun-Ra* introduced himself as *Satan* to lure them into his own mission, getting his bride *Amunet*, back.

**Note:** Please consider all the characters in the show and their previous appereances in folklore and literature. Every character (including Dracula and Mina) has a background in our universe either in folklore and myhtology or literature. From Dorian Grey to Victor Frankenstein. *It is natural that we assume things based on what we know.*

- [Quora - In *Penny Dreadful*: Who is Vanessa Ives?](https://www.quora.com/In-Penny-Dreadful-who-is-Vanessa-Ives)
- [God Amun-Ra](http://www.egyptian-witchcraft.com/god-amun-ra/)
- [Egyptian Gods - Amunet](http://egyptian-gods.org/egyptian-gods-amunet/)
- [YouTube Video of the episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQWtK6cdnYE)